# Программа: Печать массива в виде HTML таблицы

Tags: php, массивы, функции

У меня есть таблица states для хранения например 50 ти штатов.
Как напечатать названия 50 штатов США в таблице из шести столбцов.

Вот тут пытаюсь решить следующую задачу: как отрисовать  таблицу с горизонтально расположенными столбцами располагаемую фиксированное количество элементов в строке.
пока что придумал всего лишь название функции и как будет выглядеть массив

```
echo grid_horizontal(array("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","C","D","E","F","AA"),6);

echo grid_horizontal(array("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","C","D","E","F","AA"),3);
```

Я это делаю для себя,мне посоветовали набить руку на таких вот задачках, а как и с чего начать пока что не получается.

Строго не судите друзья,буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуюсь данными предоставленными вами

Первое множество заполняет начальную строку таблицы, второе множество располагается в следующей строке и так далее. Наконец доходим до последней строки, которую, возможно, придется заполнить пустыми ячейками таблицы.
Функция grid_horizontal(), показанная в примере, позволяет
указать массив и число столбцов. Она предполагает ширину таблицы,
равную 100%, но ее можно изменить с помощью переменной $table_width.

```
function grid_horizontal($array, $size) {
    $table_width = 100;
    $width = intval($table_width / $size);
    $tr = '<tr align="center">';
    $td = "<td width=\"$width%%\">%s</td>";
    $grid = "<table width=\"$table_width%\">$tr";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $e) {
        $grid .= sprintf($td, $e);
        $i++;
        if (!($i % $size)) {
        $grid .= "</tr>$tr";
        }
    }
    while ($i % $size) {
        $grid .= sprintf($td, '&nbsp;');
        $i++;
    }
    $end_tr_len = strlen($tr) * -1;
    if (substr($grid, $end_tr_len) != $tr) {
     $grid .= '</tr>';
    } else {
        $grid = substr($grid, 0, $end_tr_len);
    }
    $grid .= '</table>';
    return $grid;
}
echo grid_horizontal(array("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","C","D","E","F","AA"),6);
```

Для работы с базой пользуйтесь [Класс PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php)

```
try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");
    $query=$db->prepare("Select state from states");
    $query->excute();
    $states = [];
    while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $states[] =  $row->state;
    }
}catch(PDOException  $e ){
    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
// генерируем HTML  таблицу
$grid = grid_horizontal($states, 6);
// и печатаем ее
print $grid;
```

Comment: Avchyan  Огромное спасибо,я вам очень благодарен